# save all data in single statement without loop

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How to save all data in cakePHP. Suppose I have number of records regarding single model I wish to save all data at a time. My array is in format.

```
Array
(
[Attendance] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2013-10-09
                [user_id] => 10
                [attendance] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2013-10-09
                [user_id] => 8
                [attendance] => 0
            )
    )
)
```

Is this possible to save all data a single time. I tried to do it using saveMany but it was not successful.

Do I need to do it in loop

```
foreach ($result as $data) {
                $this->Attendance->create();
                $this->request->data['Attendance'] = $data;
                $this->Attendance->save($this->request->data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [saveMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) instead of save

```
$this->Attendance->saveMany($this->request->data);
```

data should be in this format :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Attendance] => Array
            (
                [field] => value
                [field] => value
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Attendance] => Array
            (
                [field_1] => value
                [field_2] => value
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks buddy. My sequence of `$this->request->data` was incorrect. It worked... What would it do if I send the id for few records?? Will it update those records and saved the new ones.

Comment: yes in that case it should update records if it finds ids . glad that it works for you

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP will save each record for each id you have on the array. The only requirement is to use the array structure convention by them, then use:

```
    // Check method request
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Check not empty data
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            // Save the data
            if ($this-> Attendance->save($this->request->data)) {
                // Set a session flash message and redirect.
                $this->Session->setFlash('Attendance saved.');
                $this->redirect('/Attendances');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Error saving the data.');                
            }
        }
    }
```